# Creating a class that replaces another class given certain conditions

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose there is a class A, and class B is the same class with some additional functionality in it. Given that a certain condition is met (e.g. a debug parameter was passed on command line before running), class A should be replaced with class B. How would one implement class B?

Comment: Look into dependency injection — here’s an article and video for doing it in C++: https://www.bogotobogo.com/DesignPatterns/Dependency_Injection_Design_Pattern_Inversion_Of_Control_IoC.php